# Using svelte-loadable for lazy import can I avoid passing props to component based on which component type I'm loading?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm using [`svelte-loadable`](https://github.com/kaisermann/svelte-loadable) and the below code but I'm getting the below warning and I feel this is not a good code.

Can you suggest me how to properly handle this?

The warning: `<Create> was created with unknown prop 'playerID'`

The code:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import Loadable from "svelte-loadable";
  
  export let loader: string;
  // other code
</script>

<Loadable
  loader={loader === "player"
    ? () => import("$lib/../routes/players/create.svelte")
    : () => import("$lib/../routes/teams/create.svelte")
    // others here...
  }
  let:component
>
  <svelte:component
    this={component}
    {formName}
    on:SOMETHING={handleSOMETHING}
    {/* other props here */}
    playerID={loader === "player" ? playerID : undefined}
  />
</Loadable>
```

Is there a way I can avoid the `playerID` prop based on which component I'm loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to just have an `{#if}` on `loader` and have separate `Loadable`/`svelte:component` pairs. Then you can just pass the appropriate properties.

If you do not need props with `bind` you could also have a local variable that contains the correct props based on `loader` and then spread that object. Something like:

```js
const props = loader == 'player' ?
  { playerID } :
  {};
```

```html
<svelte:component {...props} />
```